# Green terminal prompt vanished from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, prompt

It's a bit silly but as you can see, the initial words (prompt) displayed in the terminal look very simple (as you know, it has like a green color), something I didn't see at first since I executed this command: `sudo -s`.

[image]

I've tried to reboot and empty it but I don't see it changing.
I'm a newbie at this, if you know what the problem is tell me.
I have Ubuntu 20.04 64bits.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: He wants to get his bright green terminal prompt back.

Comment: Which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I was trying to install the java JRE, I saw a tutorial on youtube, I followed it because I don't know almost the commands and that happened to me.

Comment: `.bashrc` should be restored.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore the default `~/.bashrc` file by running

```
cp /etc/.bashrc ~
```

You should get the default terminal behavior back.

Answer (score 1):

**[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239091) from Pilot6 does not work for me because `/etc/.bashrc` does not exist on Ubuntu 20.04**

My solution for **Ubuntu 20.04** is to copy the value of `PS1` definitions from the `/home/skeleton/.bashrc` file that came with **Ubuntu 18.04**:

- Open two instances of terminal: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  Click inside the new terminal, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to create another terminal, to ensure you still have a terminal that has your previous `.bashrc` setup
- Backup your `/home/USER/.bashrc` file (replace USER with your login user name):

```bsh
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc-backup
```

- Edit your `/home/USER/.bashrc`:

```bsh
gedit ~/.bashrc > /dev/null 2>&1
```

- Then replace the last occurence of `PS1=` in your `/home/USER/.bashrc` with:

```bsh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

and save the file.

- run the following:

```bsh
source ~/.profile
```

- It should now display a prompt in green color

Comment: Thanks, works for me